# Swift - Is there any way I can filter closer values from an array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, maps, filtering

I got an array of location objects. ( latitude , longitude, location name).
Location is received from users gps from morning to evening.

Challenge:
I want to create trip by filtering the location objects.

For e.g.: trip 1 will contain location from one start point to another and trip 2 will contain...

User can make 2/3 trips per day.

Question:
How can I group that array containing closer(values) latitudes and longitudes in swift iOS ?

**EDIT**
**Get the data from array if the user is traveling else leave them so that from that array i can make a trip**

Any ideas highly appreciated.

Comment: It's still unclear what criteria you want to use to filter the locations array.

Comment: @RamyAlZuhouri:
how can we filter for the closer values in swift ?

Comment: Do you mean sort?

Comment: @user3804063: did you search for "sort by distance"?

Comment: @vikingosegundo: i didn't but i need to take care of the user is traveling or not . 

if user is traveling then I need to pick those values if user is not traveling then do not pick the values from array . PEEJWEEJ:

Comment: @user3804063 I don't have the foggiest idea about what you try to say.

Comment: i got array of locations from am to pm . but i need the only location which the user has travelled

Comment: sort them by distance, pick the first (aka: closest) one

Comment: @vikingosegundo: i got only latitudes and longitudes : do you got any reference for this kindly

Comment: re: @user3804063: did you search for "sort by distance"?

Comment: Use the sort(by:) function.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no way like magic code in swift for that.

How I actually solve is by traditional solving technique.
I did made a for loop and inside made a checker (which checked if two consecutive elements got time interval > 30 minutes then add the collected array elements as object to main array .

If anyone searching for such then apply you own logic.

Answer (score 0):

```
var closure:((_ sender:UIButton)->())? = nil
var closure:((_ sender:UIButton)->())? = nil
closure!(sender)
cell.closure = { (sender:UIButton) -> Void in

        debugPrint("\(indexPath.row + 1)")
        debugPrint(sender.tag)
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Comment: Please explain why or how this code answers the question. Providing an explanation will better illustrate why your answer is the best solution.